# Using modified SMS database with iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, sms, database

I've been trying to remove a specific text from my iPhone's SMS database. The text is too long (tens of thousands of characters long, if not more) and is causing iOS to crash whenever I view the conversation it's in. I'd greatly prefer to remove it without removing any other text.

I've tried downloading the SMS database file and:

1. Modifying the text to [Removed] and saving it to the phone
2. Modifying the text to [Removed], saving it, backing up, and restoring
3. Modifying the text to [Removed] and simply replacing the database file in a backup, then restoring
4. Removing the text from the database and saving it to the phone
5. Removing the text from the database, saving it, backing up, and restoring
6. Removing the text from the database and simply replacing the database file in a backup, then restoring

All of these methods have been unsuccessful. The iPhone is always unable to write to the modified database. Some of these methods don't let the iPhone read any of the texts at all (and simply have an empty Messages app) or they make the iPhone read the texts at first, but then once the phone is restarted it cannot read it anymore.
The phone is still able to read and write to the unmodified database file no problem.

I am using DB Browser for SQLite (http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to modify the database file.

I need a way to remove the text in question without viewing it in the iOS messaging app. My phone is jailbroken. I'd really like to get this fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said your phone was jailbroken.

1. Open Cydia
2. Install an app called `iFile`.
3. Open iFile.
4. Navigate to Library -> SMS -> sms.db
5. Make your edit.
6. Launch Messages.